# Логировать POST-запросы при помощи nginx

Tags: nginx, backend

У нас в продакшене запущено приложение на `Spring Boot`, которое принимает пакеты в теле метода POST. Для балансирования нагрузки используется `nginx`. Мне нужно временно логировать все пакеты, но сделать это в приложении не получится, потому что в нем используется `Swagger`. Я хочу логировать все `POST`-запросы при помощи `nginx`.

Для этого я хочу адаптировать под свое приложение такой конфиг:

```
log_format postdata $request_body;

server {
    # (...)

    location = /post.php {
       access_log  /var/log/nginx/postdata.log  postdata;
       fastcgi_pass php_cgi;
    }
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, здесь `POST`-запрос логируется, а потом передается `cgi`-обработчику. Но у меня используется не `cgi`. Приложение просто принимает пакеты и применяет к ним бизнес-логику.

Как настроить `nginx`, чтобы после логирования запроса он отправлялся REST-приложению?

В настройках сервера, которые делал сисадмин, есть такой локейшен:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://rest_api
    proxy_redirect off
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_ip
```

и прочие настройки. Как ничего не сломать, конфигурируя логирование?

Comment: Внутрь этого location и вставьте строчку access_log